# Magento 2: Include static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts) before </head>

Tags: magento2, head

How do i  Include static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts) before  in Magento 2?

i follow the docs [magento 2 Include static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

i have copied the file from base theme to the extended theme

my_extended_theme_dir/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

and here is the code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <script id="mcjs">!function(dsds){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://some script.js");    </script>
    </head>
</page>
```

but no changes, recreated static files, clear cache, reindex...
what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your `app/design/frontend/MODULE/NAME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` you can put a following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head_scripts" template="Magento_Theme::static/head.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Next, create a file `Magento_Theme/templates/static/head.phtml` and inside you can put a every JS script like e.g Google Analytics or other

Clear the cache and you should see content from `head.phtml` before close of `</head>`

Answer (score 1):

you can add this code in an phtml file path:

> Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/head.phtml

and call that file in default.xml as below

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.script" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/head.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: it's working this way, it's there a way to add scripts like this before /body tag ?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the script inside the body tag
eg.
<body>your script</body>